# Unable to understand Implementation of List in c++

Tags: c++

If I have a statement in my c++ program as

```
list < int > *adj;

adj = new list < int > [V];
```

what does `[v]` mean here does it signify size of list or number of list that are being created.

Sorry for such a silly question but I searched a lot of place but without any clear answer.

**Edit 1:** added declaration of list

Comment: It signifies an array of `list`s. So the number of lists that are being created.

Comment: Every basics book will cover this. And it´s not a list, but an array.

Comment: @deviantfan actually it's an array of lists.

Comment: You added the declaration of `adj`, not `list`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
adj = new list[V];
```

I hope you have a class `list` and it has a constructor, either default or user defined public constructor not accepting any parameter, that means it is default constructable. And `V` is an integer.

If you use simply `list adj[V]` system creates an array of `list` with size `V`, so your `list` constructor will get call `V` times.

`new` operator allocates memory and invokes the constructor.

So this statement `list* adj= new list[V]` allocates memory for V times the size of object of class list and invokes constructor of class list V times, and assigns the starting of the memory location to variable `adj`.

So to deallocate and destruct all `V` objects of `list` that you have created, you should call delete as follows

```
delete [] adj;
```

Comment: `list` needs a to be default constructable.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of expression

```
new X[N]
```

allocates an array of type X and length N, and evaluates to a pointer to its first element.

This kind of statement

```
x = new X[N];
```

assigns the result of the expression on the right hand side of the `=` to `x`.

So, you are dynamically allocating an array of `V` objects of type `list`, ans assigning a pointer to the first element to `adj`.

This has nothing to do with the implementation of `list`.

Comment: OP is a beginner I assume, I'd suggest removing abbreviations and explaining them in full words. `RHS` for example.

Comment: @JameyD I removed RHS.

Answer (score 1):

`new list[V]` means you create an `list` type  array of  length `V`

---

new is an Operator of c++,it works blow:

1. malloc rooms:  `malloc(sizeof(list)*V)`
2. do some Initializations:   call default construct function to Initializat each value in the array`
3. give the pointer of the array

`

Comment: There is no requirement that any form of `operator new` calls `malloc()`  There is also nothing preventing the array form of `operator new` from allocating more memory than requested.   In fact, a common implementation choice is allocating more for bookkeeping so the array form of operator `delete` can correctly release the specified number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

It's called the `new[]` operator.

It allocates and initializes memory for a `list` array with size `V`, and returns a `list` pointer pointing to the first element of the array.